# LDAP, tomcat, clear

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap

I have implemented LDAP authentication in my application.
But user Name password we are giving as input going in CLEAR format.
How can we send them in post method or in some encrypted format?
Please help.

Web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <description>
        </description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.eeft.login.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
        /LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Logging Area</web-resource-name>
      <description>
              Authentication for registered users. 
          </description>
      <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Please enter your Username</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

server.xml

```
<Realm alternateURL="ldap://hubp2-ads-sv2t.hubp.test.eeft.com" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" connectionURL="ldap://INPU1-ADS-SV1o" debug="99" userPattern="{0}"/>
```

Comment: Enable the TLS connector in Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Boris.. I tried not finding a way to enable TLS on tomcat. how to enable TLS. would there be any other impact on the application in case we enable TLS.

Comment: Excuse me? There is a tutorial [as part of the Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). As for your second question, do you know what TLS _is_?

Comment: Thank you Boris...SSL implemented in our production environment,we  don't need to do that in dev environment. thanks for the help.